# Python - how to kill a process, that is not started by any user, but by SYSTEM?

Tags: python, process, operating-system

I tried different methods, which are listed below, but none of them is able to kill a process if it wasn't started by current user.
Error I get every time: "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied"

Methods that were tried:

```
subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","*app name*.exe"])
os.system('TASKKILL /T /F /IM "*app name*.exe"')
os.system('wmic process where name="*app name*.exe" delete')
os.kill(2868, 9)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to kill a system process? They are crucial

Comment: @Sujay This process is a server run by a program, I can kill the program (controller) that is connected to server, but I need to kill the server itself too

Answer (score 1):

I found this sample that helped me:

```
import ctypes, sys
import subprocess

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","program.exe"])
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

However, it changes your current working directory, and everything after this code is also executed with elevated privileges. For a workaround I stuffed this piece of code into a small exe, that was executed in `subprocess.Popen()`